# Android Bluetooth pairing dialog shows less than 1 second

Tags: android, bluetooth

This post is here to help people from my brief experience with a bug of the Bluetooth pairing dialog on my phone.

**Context:**
I was unable to pair my smartwatch with my Google Pixel 5 running Android 12. When I try the pairing from the Bluetooth menu, the PIN shows on my Withings ScanWatch and the popup to enter the PIN shows on my smartphone. But after less than 1 second it closes automatically. So I wasn't able to enter the PIN :(

**What I tried:**

- restart my phone and my watch
- delete all my Bluetooth devices already paired
- delete the cache of the "Bluetooth" application
- do the pairing in safe mode

I don't want to reset my phone, so I would like to find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

- Go in the "Developer options" (search on Google if not already enabled)
- Check "Enable Gabeldorsche"

It is the new Android BLE stack written in Rust.
With this option checked, the dialog asking for the pairing PIN remains visible and gives me enough time to enter the PIN.

Hope it can help somebody ;)